# How to update items available count on candy machine UI after someone mints? Next app using umi

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v3, nextjs

I built a ui on next js using typescript and need the items available count to not only show currently available items but to update after a user mints. Currently, I'm using candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable which shows a total number of items inserted into the candy machine instead of the current available count. I'm using import { CandyMachine } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine" to work functions.

```
const CarMint = () => {
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const [pageLoading, setPageLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [candyMachine, setCandyMachine] = useState<CandyMachine | undefined>();
  const [isUserMinting, setIsUserMinting] = useState(false);
  const owner = publicKey("walletaddress");
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const umi = createUmi(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SOLANA_RPC_HOST as unknown as string)
  .use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet))
  .use(mplCandyMachine());

  const getCandyMachine = async () => {
    setPageLoading(true);
    try {
      const cmPubkey = publicKey(
        CarCandy ?? ""
      );
      const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, cmPubkey);
      if (!candyMachine) throw new Error("No Candymachine at address");
      setCandyMachine(candyMachine);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Fetching CM Error", error);
      enqueueSnackbar(
        "Fetching CM Error: Check console logs for more details",
        {
          variant: "error",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
        }
      );
    }
  
    setPageLoading(false);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getCandyMachine();
  }, []);



  const getPayMintButtonContent = () => {
    if (!candyMachine) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    if (isUserMinting) {
      return "Minting in progress..";
    } else if (candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable === BigInt(0)) {
      return "Sold out";
    } else {
      return "Free Mint";
    }
  };

  const payMintButtonClicked = async () => {
    setIsUserMinting(true);
    try {
      if (candyMachine?.publicKey) {
        const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);
    const freeMint = await transactionBuilder()
      .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
      .add(
        mintV2(umi, {
          candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
          nftMint,
          collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
          collectionUpdateAuthority: owner,
          mintArgs: {
            mintLimit: some({ id: 1 }),
            solPayment: some({ destination: owner }),
          },
          tokenStandard: TokenStandard.ProgrammableNonFungible,
        })
      )
      .sendAndConfirm(umi);
    
      console.log( "Mint Success!!!", freeMint )
      enqueueSnackbar(
        "Mint Success!!!",
        {
          variant: "success",
          anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
        }
      );
      getCandyMachine();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Mint Error", error);
      enqueueSnackbar("Mint Error: Only one per customer, Dude!!!", {
        variant: "error",
        anchorOrigin: { vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" },
      });
    }
    setIsUserMinting(false);
  };

return (
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="#ffd839" style={{
                      textAlign: "center", fontFamily: "Press Start 2P"
                    }}>
                    Remaining
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    color="textPrimary"
                    style={{
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      textAlign: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    {`${candyMachine ? candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable : "Loading.."}`}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

The presented code does refresh after mint occurs, the problem is with "candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable" It shows the total amount inserted into the candyMachine. Use candyMachine.itemsRedeem and it will give you a count that increases to the total compared to a count that decreases. Anyone wanting to use this code will need to change (candyMachine.data.itemsAvailable === BigInt(0)) to (candyMachine.itemsAvailable === BigInt("Your total number"))

Answer (score 0):

Tx confirmation takes some time so you need to add something like "await delay(5000)" before fetching Candymachine whenever you mint